# can you push just a comment on git? (like you don't want to make specific changes, but you want to add a comment)

Tags: git

So I am trying to add a comment for a project that I am working on with other people on Bitbucket, is it possible to just push a comment to the site? Since I am not trying to make changes to the file, but I do have comments to make.

Comment: By "comment" do you mean commit message?

Comment: When you say "comment", are you just trying to change the commit message, or are you referring to commenting a program like Java or C++?

Answer (score 2):

A git comment is an attribute of a commit. You cannot create a comment without creating a commit, which records changes to a file.

Git does not have comments that can be attached to a file as such (such as a feature that might be found in some collaborative document editing software suite). The commit comment is not for a specific file, but for all the changes in a commit, which can span multiple files.

Comments within a file are something else; they have nothing to do with git; git doesn't care whether some change affects code, or only a comment which is ignored by the compiler or interpreter for the source language of that file.  Altering such a comment is a change; it must be committed and pushed out like any other change.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, yes I am talking about a comment in java codes.

Answer (score 1):

This takes away from what Git is designed to do, so even if there is a way of doing it it wouldn't be a good idea.

Using BitBucket's issue tracker or wiki systen would be a much better idea.